# How can i make this script delete a folder thats within a folder

Tags: php

How can i make this script delete a folder thats within a folder the production folder has a folder called twig inside it but fails to delete

```
    <?php

// Deletes everything but index.htm and .htaccess from the phpBB cache directory

$cachedir = "cache/production";

    $dir = opendir($cachedir);    

// Delete everything but index.htm and .htaccess

    while( $file = readdir( $dir ) ) {
       if ($file == "." or $file == ".." or $file == "index.htm" or $file == ".htaccess") {
          continue;
       }
       echo "Deleting $cachedir/$file ... ";
       if (unlink("$cachedir/$file")) {
          echo "Done.<BR>";
       } else {
          echo "Not done.<BR>";
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do you have the rights to delete the folder?

Comment: https://paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory